# Questions regarding equinumerousity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $f:A \to B$ and $g:C \to D$ are one-to-one, onto functions, $A$ and $C$ are disjoint, and $B$ and $D$ are disjoint, then $f \cup g$ is one-to-one, onto function from $A \cup C$ to $B \cup D$.

Intuitively, I understand what the question asks for, since that both pairs $A$ and $C$, $B$ and $D$ are disjoint and their respective functions are one-to-one and onto, it is logically that $f \cup g$ is one-to-one, onto too. But I don't know how to put the proof in right words.

To prove that $f \cup g$ is one-to-one means that to show it is not the case that $(f \cup g)(a_1) = (f \cup g)(a_2)$ and $a_1$ not equal to $a_2$, but other than stating this, I don't know how to continue the proof. Please provide some hint or guides.

I am currently studying Daniel J. Velleman's brilliant book: How to Prove It. But I am not quite able to follow it for I have scanty knowledge regarding set theory, especially for the later chapters. Hope anyone here can provide some other book for references. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f\cup g:A\cup C\rightarrow B\cup D$ as follows

$$(f\cup g)(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x), & \text{if }x\in A \\
g(x), & \text{if }x\in C
\end{cases}$$

Now you can use the bijectivity of $f$ and $g$ and the disjointness of the sets to argue the bijectivity of $f\cup g$.

Note that $f\cup g$ is also well defined because $A$ and $C$ are disjoint

---

I'll do surjectivity.

Take $y\in B\cup D$. Then either $y\in B$ or $y\in D$ but not both since $B\cap D=\emptyset$.

If $y\in B$ then there exists a unique $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=y$ by the bijectivity of $f$. Hence $(f\cup g)(a)=y$ by definition.

The argument for $y\in D$ is analogous.

Comment: So the complete proof for injectivity will be(with reference to @hlf guide): Suppose (f∪g)(a1)=(f∪g)(a2), then (f∪g)(a1) and (f∪g)(a2) are either both in B or both in D. WLOG, suppose they are both in B, then f(a1)=f(a2) so a1=a2 by bijectivity of f.

Comment: Indeed. That is how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll continue from where you left off:
Suppose $(f \cup g)(a_1) = (f \cup g)(a_2)$. Since $B$ and $D$ are disjoint, it follows that $(f \cup g)(a_1)$ and $(f \cup g)(a_2)$ are either both in $B$ or both in $D$. Without loss of generality, suppose they are both in $B$. Then $a_1$ and $a_2$ are in $A$. Since $f: A \to B$ is one-to-one, $a_1 = a_2$.

You can do something similar for onto. Good luck!